# Is there a way to group iCloud calendars so I can turn on/off several at once?

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

For instance, I'm subscribed to 3 different sports teams calendar. Which is nice for me knowing when games are, but can be cluttering when I'm working. Now I know this is only 3 calendars so it's not a big deal to just uncheck them. But say I wanna add more.

Is there a way I can create a "sports" group or something and add them all in. I believe this feature used to exist, but now I'm on Yosemite and don't see anything like it.

Comment: are those google calendars?

Comment: @Buscar웃 They're iCal calendars, like http://www.goheels.com/export/export.dbml. They get added to my iCalendar app, I usually put them under iCloud so they go to my phone too.

Comment: Thanks, so you want all of them to open at once (in separate windows) ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yeah, I'd like some way to group, for example, all my "sports" calendars into one. So when I wanna see if there's a game on today, I just have the one checkbox. Instead of having to check/uncheck every team.

Comment: ok, that is way different then opening all at once, you want them combined in to one calendar. So for me to test, tell me which ones do you want from they list.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I commented on your answer, I like it but there's still one issue that it doesn't address. Maybe you could help me figure it out.

Edit: But also, I don't really care if they're necessarily in one calendar or not. I would just like a way to open/close all calendars of our category with one checkbox. However that's accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then here is the way to merge multiple Sports Events calendars in to your iCAL (calendar) on your Mac.

First choose which ones (one by one) and use download -Save to your Mac.

[image: ical]

Once you have them all downloaded, Open your iCal (Calendar) on your Mac.

Under File choose Import.

Locate the downloaded file and click Import. Repeat for other events calendars.

[image: save]

In my test the result is as follows.

[image: Result]

Comment: So this is a really cool idea and I like it, that could definitely work.

Only problem I see if sometimes these calendars are updated. So like the UNC Men's Basketball calendar has a game for the 7th, but the time hasn't been scheduled yet so it's not on the calendar. The calendar will update eventually, right now I have them set to update every day. So I'd be losing this functionality by actually saving the calenders and combining them.

Does that make sense?

Comment: There are 2 ways to keep them up to date. One is as described above, thus re-import calendar from time to time to get updates. Second one would be using your online Calendar (such as Google cal) and subscribe to the events, then it would be automatically updated.

Comment: I might actually be able to do closer to what I want using google cal and then just subscribing to that. Anyways, you've ever me a lot to think about. Thanks! I'm not sure there's a perfect answer here (which sucks because this feature used to exist several OS X version ago!), but I picked yours.